# How can I compare md5 checksums in Perl?

Tags: perl, comparison, md5

I'm trying to compare the checksum value of a file.
One variable `$a` has the checksum (output of `md5sum` command, only the hexadecimal part) 
and the same value is in variable `$b`.

If I do (`$a == $b`), I am getting an error, but if I do `($a eq $b)` it gives not equal.

Thanks for your answers, it worked in string comparison after trimming the white spaces, though the use of chomp din't work.

Comment: Show the command line `md5sum` output and the Perl code you are using.

Comment: Show us the data and the error. You probably don't have the data you think you have.

Comment: If you're still having trouble with this, you should consider updating your question, or commenting on an answer.

Answer (score 5):

You are comparing strings, not numbers, so do use `eq`.
Also use [`lc()`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/lc.html), and [`chomp()`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/chomp.html) or `$a=~s/^\s+//;$a=~s/\s+$//;`.
You do have the pretty decent option of converting the input to numbers with [`hex()`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/hex.html) and using `==`.
Try:

```
if (hex($a) == hex($b)){}
```

This all depends on how well you're handling the output of your `md5sum` command.  Mine looks like this:

```
dlamblin$ md5 .bash_history 
MD5 (.bash_history) = 61a4c02cbd94ad8604874dda16bdd0d6
```

So I process it with this:

```
dlamblin$ perl -e '$a=`md5 .bash_history`;$a=~s/^.*= |\s+$//g;print $a,"\n";'
61a4c02cbd94ad8604874dda16bdd0d6
```

Now I do notice that `hex()` has an integer overflow error on this so you'll want to [`use bigint;`](http://perldoc.perl.org/bigint.html)

```
dlamblin$ perl -e '
$a=`md5 .bash_history`;$a=~s/^.*= |\s+$//g;print hex($a),"\n";'
Integer overflow in hexadecimal number at -e line 1.
1.29790550043292e+38
dlamblin$ perl -Mbigint -e '
$a=`md5 .bash_history`;$a=~s/^.*= |\s+$//g;print hex($a),"\n";'
129790550043292010470229278762995667158
```

Answer (score 4):

Make sure that your strings don't have new-lines or other characters at the end. If in doubt, `chomp()` both then compare. Also (just to cover off the exceedingly obvious), they are both using the same case to encode the hex chars?

Comment: Instead of all that regex, just:
md5 .bash_history | perl -lane 'print pop @F'
(or shift @F if you are using md5sum).

Comment: @Emil: what regex?  and instead of perl, |rev|cut -f 1 -d ' '|rev :)

Answer (score 1):

If ($a eq $b) is false, then they are indeed not equal.  If you've ruled out obvious differences like "filename: " on one of them, you need to look for whitespace or nonprintable character differences.  The easy way to do that is:

```
use Data::Dumper;
$Data::Dumper::Useqq=1;
print Dumper($a);
print Dumper($b);
```

Comment: For debugging scalars I find it easier to just do `print "[$a] [$b]";`

Comment: @friedo: that works...unless you have tabs vs. spaces, or nul chars, etc.